# Glyphicon won't fully hide on CSS3 Hover Animation

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-transitions, css-animations

Does anyone know how I can make the blue icon disappear when you hover over the white background of the card? I tried to set up the animation for it to happen whenever the mouse touches anywhere in the card and not just directly over the icon.

It's wonky right now. The blue icon blinks when you put your mouse near it and eventually it disappears for a second but then it comes back. Not smooth at all.

Thank you for your help.

```css
body {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
.fa {
  margin-top: 40px;
  color: #0088ce; 
}
.textanim-container {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 360px;
  min-height: 243px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 4px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
.textanim-title {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.textanim-container:hover {
  top: 10px;
  transform: bottom 0.64s, opacity 0.63s cubic-bezier(0.33, 0.66, 0.66, 1)
}
.textanim-hidden {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  /*opacity: 0.5;*/
  transition: 0.8s;
  text-align: center;
  right: 3px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.textanim-container:hover .textanim-hidden {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: #444;
  /*background-color: #0088ce;*/
  /*color: #fff;*/
}
.disappear:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

/*
.fa:hover {
  color: #fff;
}*/
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="textanim-container text-center disappear">
  <div class="disappear">
  <i class="fa fa-user fa-4x disappear" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <h3 class="textanim-title disappear">One Account Manager</h3>
  </div>
  <span class="textanim-hidden">
    For groups over 100, we assign a single account manager, someone who'll get to know your group and respond quickly to queries. Under 100? You'll still get the benefit of our AMs' expertise—and one number, one email.
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display:none` to icon when you hover over white block.

```css
body {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
.fa {
  margin-top: 40px;
  color: #0088ce; 
}
.textanim-container {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 360px;
  min-height: 243px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 4px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
.textanim-title {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.textanim-container:hover {
  top: 10px;
  transform: bottom 0.64s, opacity 0.63s cubic-bezier(0.33, 0.66, 0.66, 1)
}
.textanim-container:hover .fa-user{
  display:none;
}
.textanim-hidden {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  /*opacity: 0.5;*/
  transition: 0.8s;
  text-align: center;
  right: 3px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.textanim-container:hover .textanim-hidden {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: #444;
  /*background-color: #0088ce;*/
  /*color: #fff;*/
}
.disappear:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

/*
.fa:hover {
  color: #fff;
}*/
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="textanim-container text-center disappear">
  <div class="disappear">
  <i class="fa fa-user fa-4x disappear" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <h3 class="textanim-title disappear">One Account Manager</h3>
  </div>
  <span class="textanim-hidden">
    For groups over 100, we assign a single account manager, someone who'll get to know your group and respond quickly to queries. Under 100? You'll still get the benefit of our AMs' expertise—and one number, one email.
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post the code with the change so I could run it! This did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

add below code to your css to fix the isssue

```
.textanim-container:hover .fa.fa-user{
  display:none;
}
```